# Подскажите как добавить в SearchView список?

Tags: android, cursoradaper, android-search-view

Подскажите как добавить в `SearchView` список?

У меня есть `SearchView` и список в `String[]`. В `SearchView` есть только setSuggestionsAdapter которйы принимает CursorAdapter.

Каким образом мне добавить `String[]` в `CursorAdapter`?

Хочу чтобы `SearchView` как в `PlayMarket` работал по принципу ввел слово он проверяет и выдает наиболее похожие слова в выпадающем меню `SearchView`

Comment: Что значит "наиболее похожие слова"? совпадение по фильтру (начальные введенные буквы), синонимы введенного, содержащие в себе такие же буквы, как введеные или что

Comment: да совпадение по фильтру. Ну как в Play markete вы же не раз использовали маркет и знаете что там есть поиск. после ввода появляется снизу выбор нужного слова. Такое же сделать хочу

Comment: В API есть готовый виджет [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/autocompletetextview.php)/ Вы можете [подключить к нему и CursorAdapter](http://hello-android.blogspot.ru/2011/06/using-autocompletetextview-with-sqlite.html). Никаких дополнительных String[] туда передавать не нужно.

Comment: @pavlofff, Это все хорошо. но Я хочу добавить AutoCompleteTextView в Actionbar. Для это SearchView то что нужно. А AutoCompleteTextView не добавить таким образом.

Comment: Как [добавить AutoCompleteTextView](http://dj-android.blogspot.ru/2013/04/android-autocompletetextview-inside.html) в ActionBar

Comment: SearchView [тоже можно использовать](http://www.journaldev.com/12478/android-searchview-example-tutorial), в принципе, но там нет такого выпадающего меню поверх экрана, как у AutoCompleteTextView. Прикручивать все это слишком хлопотно, когда есть уже готовое решение

Comment: спс. Дайте ответ я закросю тему